# iOS app not uninstall and reinstalling between tests on Browserstack App Automate

Tags: ios, cucumber, browserstack

Currently running a smoke test suite on IntelliJ against Browserstack App Automate (Java, Appium, and Cucumber to write the test files).

The issue comes from running iOS tests as a series/suite. When one test ends and another begins, the app hasn't reset or reinstalled and starts from where the other app ended (with a new user created). For each test, we need the app to start from afresh and this doesn't seem to be happening. Android tests for our app work just fine, but this issue only happens when running them on iOS.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

Could you execute the tests by setting the capability "fullReset" to "true". Read more on this in the link: http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/other/reset-strategies/index.html

Then execute the command "**driver.resetApp()**" after the execution of one test and before the beginning of the second?

Comment: Thanks! Turns out the capability for fullReset had a dash in the middle.